# Dual LAN on one NIC and routing

Tags: routing, local-area-network

I'm trying replace three Windows XP workstations with new ones running Windows 7 Pro, on a network which I did not setup and can't change.
The old workstations had one NIC each with the following IPv4 settings

```
IP:192.168.1.x and 10.64.48.x
MASK:255.255.255.0 and 255.0.0.0
GATEWAY:10.64.98.1
DNS:10.95.1.16, 10.95.1.18
```

The 10.x.x.x network is a WAN which many departments around the country are connected to it, and provides Internet access via a proxy.
The 192.168.1.0/24 network is the local network with 6 workstations and windows server 2003 running a database and a shared folder.
The workstations and the server all have two IPs one for each network.

My problem is that on random occassions the workstations can't ping the server, which means they can't work on the shared folder. The way the network is setup means that when the workstations ping an IP of the 192.168.1.0/24 network, it has to go through the gateway on the 10.x.x.x network right? Unfortunately that network is usually congested, which means packet loss, which probably causes my problem.

Is there a way to route all local traffic directly, without installing a second NIC?

Comment: The answer is most likely "Yes", but we'd need to know what OS your workstations are running to get any more specific than that.

Comment: If the server is accessed via the 192 network and your workstations are also on the 192 network, then replies will NOT route via the 10 network but by the locally connected 192 network.  It's hard to understand your description.  Your network sounds a little messy to be honest.

Comment: Yes the server is accessed via the 192 network. However on random occassions I can't reach/ping it. The network is very messy, but as I said I didn't set it up and I can't change anything. My only job was to replace the workstations and make them work, but I had no idea I would find this mess.

Comment: If the computers have an IP address on the 192.168.1.0/24 range, then the packet loss is entirely unrelated to the 10.0.0.0/8 range. Assuming these workstations are windows, run "route print" and search for an entry for 192.168.1.0, you should see that traffic is routed out of the local secondary nic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the packets will not be routed through the 10.x network, as you have an on-link route for the 192.168.1.0/24 network. You should be able to see this fine using a `tracert` on the servers's IP.

You would need to fire up wireshark for example and see if you can see a cause for the packet loss.
Also, have a look at the switch and it's statistics.

But it could prove to be quite hard if all you have is the workstation and no access to anything else